# Consume a service from a Master node

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to consume a service running in a computer from another computer in the same network. Is this possible?

I have set up ROS_MASTER_URI correctly on both, I know its correct since I was able to do the talker/listener example from the tutorials.

If I run roscore and the service from the basic tutorial:

```
rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py
```

and this on the client computer:

```
rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_client.py
```

I get nothing.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: One runs the server and one runs the client, I do not have the server running on both computers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246184/consume-a-service-from-a-master-node/) by [anonymous28122](https://answers.ros.org/users/28122/anonymous28122/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-10-21**:
You should only need one copy of the server node; why are you running it on both computers?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-22**:
Just to clarify: @ahendrix asks why you run `add_two_ints_server.py` on both your server and your client. You write: "I get nothing", but that makes sense, as the servers will just sit there, waiting for a client to connect, which you don't start.

**Comment by [anonymous28122](https://answers.ros.org/users/28122/anonymous28122/) on 2016-10-24**:
Im sorry, I typed in both the same script, but one of those should be running a client. I edited my post to address this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to specify the input arguments : the two numbers that you're going to add, when calling the client.

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0